# Need help with spaces within math mode

Tags: math-mode

My code is written as follows:

```
\begin{equation}
\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \cos(x+2\pi)=\cos(x)  and  \sin(x+2\pi)=\sin(x)
\end{equation}
```

But when I 'execute' it there is no space between `cos(x)` & `and` so can you help me cope with this issue? Thanks in advance!

PS: if someone could teach me how to define a new environment so that

```
\begin{theorem}Equation\end{theorem}
```

produces immediately a mathbox with the equation inside of it?, I would greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: `\begin{equation}
\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \cos(x+2\pi)=\cos(x) \quad\text{and}\quad  \sin(x+2\pi)=\sin(x)
\end{equation}` (requires `amsmath`).

Comment: Works fine thanks!